# Right border missing on search input

Tags: bug, design, search-box

Today I noticed a strange behavior of the right border of the search input in Chromium based browsers. At the first load the right border is missing:

[image: Screenshot]

If I focus the input, the border appears and stays even if I unfocus the input again. This bug appears only if you are logged in and on large screens. I also could only reproduce it in Chromium based browsers. Firefox works perfectly for me.

I'm using Ubuntu, so this bug is not only on Windows.

Comment: Can't reproduce it on Chrome 75 on Windows 10. I went to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) and can see the entire seach bar, borders and all. Not sure if relevant but I'm not logged in.

Comment: @VLAZ yes if you are not logged in it works perfectly. As I mentioned _"This bug appears only if you are logged in"_ - Can you please try when logged in?

Comment: Can't reproduce in Chrome 75 on macOs Mojave. I'm logged in.

Comment: Reproduced chrome 75 Windows 10 64bit, on this question page (and every other page I checked on both meta and non-meta), screen is 1920x1080, 100% zoom, no scaling. Logged in

Comment: No repro on Chrome 75 on Linux Mint 18.3, no matter how I zoom or resize the window. (Logged in, two 1920x1200 screens). Possibly a Windows-only bug?

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 75, Windows 10 64-bit. But damn it, it just went away while I wrote this comment!

Comment: **tldr;** *It is reproducible* Reproducible on `Chrome 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)`, but my screen resolution is set to 2560x1440 and 200% zoom due to my 14" display(win 10), when set to 1920x1080, 100% zoom, it is reproducible.

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 75, Windows. The weird thing is: if you open the page in the new tab and wait for it to load without switching it, then everything works normally. When, on the other hand, you open it in in the current tab, the right border is missing every time.

Comment: That circle's a little too thick...

Comment: Yep, see it on MacOS Chrome 76.0.3809.87. I'm not so sure if this is any kind of CSS bug in the site, the border sort of warps in and out when I resize the window really slowly. Seems more like some weird rounding artifact.

Answer (score 13):

Reproduced on Chrome 75, Windows 10 64-bit. But I did notice something interesting.

(At least in Chrome), if you zoom to any level other than 100% the issue goes away and you cannot reproduce the missing border until you refresh the page.

Also, if you focus the search bar (i.e clicking on it), the issue goes away likewise.

**Edit 1:** Also changing the screen size in any way (resizing the browser, opening devtools, etc.) makes the border re-appear.

Answer (score 5):

### Windows 10 1809 17763.557

✓ **Reproduced** Google Chrome Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

✕ **Unable to reproduce** Firefox 67.0 (64-bit)

✕ **Unable to reproduce** Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0

### MacOS 10.15 Catalina

Weirdly,

✕ **Unable to reproduce** Google Chrome Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Note: The border is briefly there when the page first loads - it appears that when the menu to the right of the search bar shifts over (once it fills with icons), this is when it disappears.

[image]