# Unclear activity for Top Questions

Tags: feature-request, user-experience, question-lists

Recently, I posted an answer this question here: [Right border missing on search input](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386849/right-border-missing-on-search-input). After going back to Top questions, I noticed this;

[image]

The wording here for me is a little unclear. As it is now, it looks like I have "Edited" or "Changed" that question in some way - however, I only posted an answer. Shouldn't this say something like "Answered 57 mins ago..."? This would make it consistent with newly asked questions, which say "Asked x mins ago..."

Comment: Pretty sure there is a dupe somewhere, but I can't find it. [This uber-meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229665/348149) says it's been implemented already, but it doesn't seem to be the case. The cake is a lie.

Comment: Pretty sure it does say "answered" when you first post the answer. If you edit your answer after posting it, it changes to "modified". Are you sure you didn't edit the answer before seeing the "modified" text?

Comment: Not 100% sure, no. Even then, that would still be strange to imply that I edited the question when the modification was on an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You answered the question and then [edited your answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/387012/revisions) about five minutes later, hence "modified". You can also see the timeline view (click toggle format to see timestamps).

> [image: timeline of answer]

Your screenshot was taken much later.

We mark a question as "modified" when anything happens on the question or answers other than the question being asked or answered. Most changes make the post active and for the statement and time references to be correct we must recognize all actions, not only those on the question.

Since you edited, that's what the action reflects. The question was answered 15 minutes before your second edit, meaning that if we'd said "answered 57 minutes ago" it'd be incorrect as the answer was posted 72 minutes prior.

Also "modified" is a link, so if you want to see what was modified, click it.

Comment: _Also "modified" is a link_ that really isn't clear. Shouldn't the "modified" part  be in red then, like OP's name or at least look like a link

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While this makes sense and I can understand the logic, I still think the wording could be better - In its current form the wording makes it appear as if I'm the OP rather than somebody who has just interacted with the question in some way.

Comment: @Lewis the info box on there shows the last activity done to the thread (the question or any answers on that question). The same display is used when you sort the questions by "active".

Comment: @Tas The "modified" part is in a light grey, just like many of the other links in this page: the "share, edit, flag" options are links, the "yesterday" / "XX hours ago" timestamp next to comments is a link. All of them are in the same shade of grey as the "modified" link. The question title in the list is also in a shade of grey, just darker to make it stand out. The tags are also links, and also a shade of grey in their own way. Red here does not mean "link", it means "we want this link to stand out in this grey world" and is reserved for usernames, help/delete links, user-supplied links etc.